# Get rid of specific local commits with git

Tags: git, merge, atlassian-sourcetree

Here is my scenario. 
I'm working against branch A. I merged a feature branch locally from branch B into branch A. After that I have done a few changes on branch A and made a commit Y. I noticed that the merge caused issues and I need to undo this merge and leave only the Y commit. 
I have not pushed from local to remote branch. All the changes are on the outgoing commits.
How can I do that without losing the work done on commit Y but just pushing that one? 
thanks

BTW: I'm using Source Tree(I know possibly this will be a command line but if anyone know how to do that using source tree that would be awesome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as nothing in commit Y directly conflicts with any of the merged changes from branch B you should be able to run an interactive rebase and drop the merge commit. I'm not familiar with Source Tree, so I can provide terminal commands:

(from branch A): `git rebase -i HEAD~3` (arbitrary 3, you just need to see a few commits)

Find the merge commit, and following the interactive rebase instructions you can change the word `pick` to `drop`. Save and quit, and git will replay the commits, but skip the commit that you specified to drop.

Note: If you're uncomfortable about losing work, I suggest you push to your remote repo, then attempt the interactive rebase. If it works as you want, then force update your repo, and if it doesn't work as expected, you'll have the backup to pull from.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the right answer (use `git rebase -i`) but you won't need to explicitly drop the merge commit, because `git rebase -i` will do it for you: The default for rebase is to discard merges. Using `git rebase -p` tries to preserve merges (it actually has to *re-create* them, which has some minor perils) but it's generally unwise to combine that with `git rebase -i` anyway.

Comment: I'll put this in as a separate comment because it's a separate idea: Rather than pushing to another repository, if one is a bit nervous, it's simpler to create a new branch name to preserve the current commit-chain. Just run `git branch saveme` before running your `git rebase -i`. When your rebase finishes, branch `saveme` will have your original (pre-rebase) commits, and your current branch will have your new (post-rebase) copies. If all is good, you can then `git branch -D saveme` to toss the saved originals. (In fact, rebase saves your originals for you under the special name `ORIG_HEAD`.)